# Visual Studio Code's "Run Test | Debug Test" option missing from unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, go, visual-studio-code

I used to see  "Run Test | Debug Test" links top of every test function in VS Code for Go. But they are missing now. How can I re-enable them?

This picture shows what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Do your test functions respect the naming convention (`Test` prefix followed by an uppercase letter) and expected signature (one `*testing.T` parameter, no results)?

Comment: yes they are. for example: func TestGetConfig(t *testing.T) {

Comment: uninstall all plugins and install go plugin again and check if it is working for you

Comment: @ManjeetThakur This sounds like an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this situation when there are many folders in the project I opened in VScode. But these options appear only when I open the folder containing the script I want to run the test in in a new window in VSCode. I don't know why, it's weird.

Answer (score 3):

Check your options to confirm that the Go test explorer is enabled:

- Preferences > Settings > User Settings > find "go test enable code lens"

[image: go test explorer]

Comment: it is already enabled but i ca't see that links anyway

Comment: sorry, I have revised my answer. so, can you check that too?

Comment: i checked but it didn't work too

Comment: Your answer mentions "go **test** enable code lens" but your screenshot just says "go enable code lens". Was the **test** bit a mistake or was the screenshot the wrong one?

Comment: super strange. Can you file an issue to https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues ? Find the troubleshooting guide - we will need the language server log if you are using the language server. @rsmnarts

Answer (score 3):

Taken directly from the [go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) doc for the `testing` package

- *To write a new test suite, create a file whose name ends _test.go that contains the TestXxx functions as described here. Put the file in the same package as the one being tested.*

Please ensure that your test file name ends in `_test.go`, and that the function you're trying to test starts with `Test` (like it does in your snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here - simply closed down VS Code and opened it back up again... they all appeared once more.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, though I was writing **`Javascript`** (not `Go`).

To fix that, I need to make sure **the Es6 `import` & `export` statements** are **correct** (*-- correctly importing `the correct item` from `the correct file path`*),, -- for `this current test js file` & `relevant imported js files` (or even all files in current project).

(Then you must save `the test js file` to refresh it.)

The `Test Explorer`'s `Output` panel may(?<) throw an Error to indicate that.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue today. In my case opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and running "OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp" fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to restating OmniSharp, you might want to make sure the right solution is selected.
Ctrl + Shift + P > select OmniSharp: Select Project > select the correct .sln file for your solution