# (WSL2 VSCode) Go CodeLens not showing run test | debug test

Tags: go, codelens

I've been trying to learn Golang backend development and have been following this Youtube guide

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLy_6D98if3ULEtXtNSY_2qN21VCKgoQAE

But when learning about writing tests i've found that my vscode doesn't display the 'run tests | debug tests' Codelens. I'm running my vscode from my WSL2 Ubuntu using the 'code .' command.

[code and proj structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqZkn.png)

I was also wondering if the command  `go test ./db/sqlc/ -run TestCreateAccoun` offers that same functionality as this codelens?

The steps that i've tried already have been to

- disable and re-enable the 'Editor: Code Lens' setting in preferences
- restart my WSL
- reinstall go extension
- Double check documentation, I follow the file naming convention ending in _test.go and my function starts with Test [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/testing)
- followed debugging steps described by others in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966822/visual-studio-codes-run-test-debug-test-option-missing-from-unit-tests) but nothing worked

I was wondering if anyone knew further debug steps - i'm willing to give necessary output.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues Bug reports should go to GitHub directly, https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, `go test ./db/sqlc/ -run TestCreateAccount` is indeed equivalent to the `run test` button in VS Code. The `debug test` button starts the debugger.

Regarding your initial question, are the `Go > Test Explorer: Enable` and `Go > Tasks: Provide Default` checkmarks set? You can find these through **Settings > Settings > User Settings > search for "go test enable"** as shown in attached image.  [image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've disabled and re-enabled both the `Go > Test Explorer: Enable` and `Go > Tasks: Provide Default`,  but i'm still not having any luck being able to see the code lens on my tests. 

Thank you for confirming my question about the go test command, i'll probably continue using that, while I send in a bug report on the github page, as per another comment.